# For external hive tables, how to design directories to add the partitions

Tags: hive

In the case of hive external tables , where the metadata will be stored ?
Should it also be assumed that the data is already organized in directory structure based on the partitioned column for us to apply the dynamic partitioning on external tables

Comment: Hive stores metadata in a RDBMS -- Derby, MySQL, Postgres, Oracle, whatever. No difference there between managed and external tables.

Comment: The reason Hive has EXTERNAL tables is that you often need a wrapper around data files that are built by an **external process** (e.g. Flume, Pig, Cascading etc). In that scenario Hive does not create the files nor the directory structure -- either new directories follow the Hive naming convention, and you just need to "repair" the table periodfically to auto-detect new partitions; or it's the external process that creates custom directories then creates new Hive partitions on these custom LOCATIONs.

Comment: Bottom line: technically, you can use Hive to "feed" an EXTERNAL table, with dynamic partitioning using the default Hive directory naming convention. But then why declare the table as EXTERNAL????